# Reducing the time between checks on a Nagios server

Tags: nagios

Can anyone let me know how I would reduce time between Last Check Time and Next Scheduled Check on a particular service. I have a very critical task to monitor and the time between checks is currently 5 minutes, which is too long for this service. Can I reduce that time? I need this to be 1 minute or even 30 seconds.

I want Nagios to check this service every 30 seconds. I currently have defined the service as follows:

```
define service{
        use                     local-service
        host_name               OpenSIP,test-RTSIP
        service_description     SIP Registration
        check_command           check_nrpe!check_sipreg
        check_freshness         0
        freshness_threshold     900
        active_checks_enabled   1
        passive_checks_enabled  1
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

Sure, reduce the `check_interval` on the service to be whatever you want it to be.  Remember that the check interval is in units of the `interval_length` global directive, which is typically set to 60 seconds.

Comment: Note that you can also (just tested this in Nagios4) specify `check_interval` in fractions, like  `check_interval 0.5`; this would if `interval_length` is 60 seconds (which it is by default) result in a check every 30 seconds.